# What is the difference between query-methods find…By, read…By, query…By, and get…By in spring data?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was looking at [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) of spring data, and didn't find a reasons to use methods `read...By`, `get...By` instead of `find...By` (as it usually done).
Please clarify:

- what does this methods do?
- or what is purpose of this methods is?
- In what cases better use this methods?
- what is the difference between them?

Could you write an example of `query..By` method?

Comment: There is no difference between these four approaches. These have been provided as options to suit individual preferences as different developers may have different preferences for how they would like to name their accessor methods. `Foo findByName (String name)`, `Foo getByName (String name)`, `Foo queryByName (String name)` and `Foo readByName (String name)` are all equivalent - they will find a `Foo` with a name matching the value passed as the `name` parameter.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

EDIT: 
This answer covers Spring query creation mechanism described in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) 
If you are looking for the differences between concrete methods `findById(..)` vs `getById(..)` you can find nice desciption [here](https://www.javacodemonk.com/difference-between-getone-and-findbyid-in-spring-data-jpa-3a96c3ff) (thanks to @smile comment)

ORIGINAL ANSWER: 
I don't know how about other subprojects, but for Spring Data JPA (1.10.2) these methods will work as aliases. Each method invocation will generate identical criteria query (and identical SQL query).

Internally there is no distinction between these prefixes. It's used only for query pattern matching:

```
private static final String QUERY_PATTERN = "find|read|get|query|stream";
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/8bc022ebd7097b921ae1ef6c87f0ae9fc05bba5f/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/PartTree.java#L54

The same approach is used for `remove...By` vs `delete...By` methods:

```
private static final String DELETE_PATTERN = "delete|remove";
```

Comment: Saw good explanation here:https://www.javacodemonk.com/post/87/difference-between-getone-and-findbyid-in-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Upvote for sharing the very place where it is implemented!

Answer (score 7):

I think this will help you to understand..

> The difference between the two interfaces lies in the semantic of their methods. The CRUD repository “finds” something whereas the JPA repository “gets” something. While “find” might lead to no result at all, “get” will always return something – otherwise the JPA repository throws an exception.

source: https://tuhrig.de/find-vs-get/

You can see this post also. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182113/how-and-why-to-decide-between-naming-methods-with-get-and-find-prefixes

Comment: Have you actually tried this? For me `get` is returning `null` just like `find`..

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that accepted answer is incorrect. It is different internally in both cases:

- `getById()` returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier. It invokes `EntityManager.getReference()` and **returns a lazy proxy**. So when you are out of transaction with this response - you will get LazyInitializationException when trying to get lazy fields.
- `findById()` **fetches real object** from database.

Comment: Question refers to query creation mechanism (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation). 
These methods you mention are not part of that mechanism, they are concrete implementations that have a different purpose.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109941/1112963

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how Spring implemented this in the past, but at least currently it's not correct that they are the same (just alias).

(This part above is incorrect from the original accepted)

Spring JPA is a layer on top of JPA. Therefore each of these operations is mapped to a *Standard JPA* operation:

`findById(id)` -> [on JPA] `entityManager.find`

Whilst,
`getOne(id)` -> [JPA] `entityManager.getReference`

So what's the difference on JPA then?

`entityManager.find` goes directly to the DB, executes the query and returns all mapped columns to the memory. Pretty straightforward.

`entityManager.getReference` is less used (it's less known). It's sort of a *lazy* find.
That is, it doesn't go directly to the DB. It only goes when the data is used. Its main target is when you just want a reference to some entity, but you won't use the entity (the values of the columns).

For instance:

```
class Customer {
    Long id;
    ... many other fields
}

class Order {

    Customer customer;
    // ... other
}
```

You want to save a new `Order`:

```
var order = new Order();

// Opt 1 (find): goes directly to DB and loads everything from this customer. Even tough we don't need it all.  
// order.setCustomer(repo.findById(123L));  
// ...    
// Opt 2 (get): Won't go to DB at this point - but rather get a reference to a specific id   
// When saving, may throw exception if customer with given id doesn't exist  
order.setCustomer(repo.getOne(123L));  
orderRepo.saveOrUpdate(order);
```

You can check a whole article explaining the diff, and better about `getReference` here: https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/.
The article isn't about Spring, but again, Spring JPA just follows JPA.

Comment: Question refers to query creation mechanism (docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/…). These methods you mention are not part of that mechanism, these methods have concrete implementations and have a different purpose