# Spring @Transactional managing entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I have some uncatchable bug in my work.

For example, I have code that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "message_generator")
    private long id;

    private long massMessageId;
}

public class MessageDTO {
    public final long id;
    public final long massMessageId;
}

@Transactional
@Service
public class ExtendedMessageService {
   private MessageService messageService;

   public MessageDTO createMessage(MessageCreateDTO createDTO) {
       var messageDTO = messageService.create();
       return messageService.linkMassMessage(messageDTO.id, createDTO.massMessageId);
   }
}

@Transactional
@Service
public class MessageService {
    private final MessageRepository repository;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public MessageDTO create() {
         var message = new Message();
         var savedMessage = repository.save(message);
         return mapper.map(savedMessage, MessageDTO.class);
    }
    
    public MessageDTO linkMassMessage(long messageId, long massMessageId) {
         var message = repository.findById(messageId)
             .orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Message with id " + id + " was not found"));
         return mapper.map(repository.save(message.setMassMessageId(massMessageId)), MessageDTO.class);
    }
}
```

What will happen in this situation? I have some bugs, when repository.findById(id) can't find entity and throws exception.
And i have no reason, why this bug is only on prod (i tried to repeat it on dev and nothing succeeded)

And when i try to find the reason of it, i get a question:
"Can i save entity and get it in one transaction in Spring?"

Comment: @TheOnly1 Could you please add more real code?

Comment: @v.ladynev yea, I was slightly wrong, I didn't saw that ```@Transactional``` on first class. I couldn't edit first comment so I deleted it. Anyway according to this example with default propagation of ```@Transactional``` the transaction should be set only on doSomething method, and persist should occur after leaving this function. ```@Transactional``` on class B and C won't matter because spring will detect that there is an active transaction and won't create new one.

Comment: @TuanHoang, thank you for answer. I understand, that in normal way I need to commit transaction. The question is more about "Can Spring or Hibernate find not flushed entity in transaction context? Or there are some other ways to do it?"

Comment: @v.ladynev thank you for correcting me. @ TheOnly1,in that case, I am sorry about that, and I would like to delete the comment for less confusion.

Comment: @TuanHoang Always ready to help :)

Answer (score 3):

**How saving works**

1. `repository.save()` doesn't save anything to database, this method puts entity to the session (persistent context) in memory.
2. flush step — on this step actual `SQL insert` happens. It can be invoked manually `repository.saveAndFlush()`, `repository.flush()`. Hibernate can do flush in the background, before operations that can use saved to the database value, like JPQL statements.
   Also flush happens when the end of `@Transactional` boundary is reached.

**What can be an issue**

You are using incorrect method. This method from the old version of Spring data and it doesn't perform search in the database. You have to use `findById()` method instead.

[Hibernate: findById vs getbyId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109649/hibernate-findbyid-vs-getbyid)

The most simple way, if you want to use id after save — flush the data immediately.

```java
Entity entity = new Entity(some_information);
repository.saveAndFlush(entity);

Entity findedEntity = repository.findById(entity.getId())
  .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Can't find id=" + entity.getId()));
```

Hibernate will not necessary perform SQL `select` to get `findedEntity`. It can get it from the session, if it happens in the same `@Transactional` boundaries.
So if the above code resides in the method with `@Transaction` SQL will not performed. if there is not `@Transaction` SQL will be performed.

**About this question**

> "Can Spring or Hibernate find not flushed entity in transaction context? Or there are some other ways to do it?"

Hibernate can't find not flushed entity. if `id` is autogenerated, Hibernate needs to perform `SQL INSERT` (flush) to get the id from a database. Another option to set up an id manually. Probably in this case it will be possible to get an entity from the persistent context.

Comment: thank you for answer. it's very helpful for me. and after your comment i fully rework my issue. sorry for bad wording. my bad...

Comment: @TheOnly1 Always ready to help. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice answer. Voted ;)